# How do I make Qt's BorderLayout items resizable?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, layout

I'm trying to create an application with layout similar to Qt's [BorderLayout example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layouts-borderlayout.html) and I'm using it as a template. How can I make regions resizable by dragging mouse on the border between them like with QSplitter?

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question itself. You're very welcome to post an answer to your own question. Please revert to the previous edit, and write a proper answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem without using BorderLayout at all:

```
QTextBrowser *centralWidget = new QTextBrowser;
centralWidget->setPlainText(tr("Central widget"));

QLabel* west = createLabel( "West" );
QLabel* east = createLabel( "East" );
QLabel* south = createLabel( "South" );

QSplitter* splitter = new QSplitter();

splitter->addWidget(west);
splitter->addWidget(centralWidget);
splitter->addWidget(east);

QSplitter* splitter2 = new QSplitter( Qt::Orientation::Vertical );
splitter2->addWidget( splitter );
splitter2->addWidget( south );
```